# Problems with binding DataGrid to XmlDataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection x:Key="ns">
        <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="a" Uri="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" />
    </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
    <XmlDataProvider XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource ns}" x:Key="SearchArtistDataSource" XPath="/a:metadata/a:artist-list/a:artist" Source="file.xml" />
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="SearchArtistDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SearchArtistDataSource}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=a:name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=a:country}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is the XML file that I'm using: http://pastebin.com/5bUCBisB

What I have achieved so far is somewhat binding the DataGrid to XmlDataProvider - I can tell so much because it autogenerates some columns out of the XML file. The problem is that the manual ones I'm trying to add (displaying name and country of artists from the artist-list array) - nothing shows up in them.

For what it's worth - a similar approach worked fine in a ListView, I got stuck while migrating.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on the MSDN forums... hindsight is strong with this one.

The `XmlNamespaceManager` has to be attached not only to the `XmlDataProvider`, but also to the `DataGrid` itself:

```
<DataGrid Binding.XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource ns}">
```

Let's hope this helps anyone who'll ever have a similar problem.